# How do I store all record change in history, so that I can keep track easily in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner at MySQL.
I have a table with 160rows .
I need to keep tracking this table everytime someone make change to all row ,
example

```
tabelname = customer
id 
user_id
name 
lastname
datebirth
accupation
spouse
etc...
etc..
```

until 160 rows in total

When someone changes a record, let say `datebirth`, I need all detail record in the history table.
When someone changes 10times, I need all the records to change, so I have 10 save records on history tables.

Comment: By rows, do you mean columns?

Comment: yes. I mean colum. can you help me please. maybe with code examples

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain another table for history. Whenever any update happen in base table you just need to copy current row to history table and you can additionally maintain user_id (user who updated row) and timestamp (time when update occurred). This way you can fetch the history of the row with group by operation on customer_id, time etc.

For Implementation you can follow this approach - https://dev.to/zhiyueyi/design-a-table-to-keep-historical-changes-in-database-10fn

for more info - 1-> [SQL history table design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710103/sql-history-table-design)
2-> [how to have a history of the Sql table column.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50057486/how-to-have-a-history-of-the-sql-table-column)
3-> [How to store historical records in a history table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890868/how-to-store-historical-records-in-a-history-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: thank you for your answer. please can you give me code examples.

Comment: I need more understanding better. thank you in advance

Comment: thank you for your help. but I need more understanding . can you point me to code. I dont need to insert whole column into mysql code. thank you

Comment: Updated answer with a link. hope it help